# Not including value rating from previous program

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that shows if an Applicant was part of certain program and it will average out their rating from previous programs and current programs. Once an applicant is added to a new program their rating is a 0 to start but it will not be included in the overall average rating unless someone gives them a different rating bigger than 0, however, if this person is removed from a current program and then later added again to that same program then it includes the value 0 to the overall rating. I don't want that but I've been trying to solve this issue that my brain is all scrambled. I have put the code that gets all Applicants with their respective programs, previous programs, and rating. Any help on this? I hope I made sense.

```
public async Task<T> GetAllApplicants()
        {
            // Other Code up here
            IList<T> participants = await GetAllParticipants();
            // applicants is being set somewhere else
            foreach (var applicant in applicants)
            {
                applicant.Programs = participants
                    .Where(p => p.Email.EqualsIgnoreCase(applicant.Email))
                    .Select(p => p.ProgramName)
                    .ToList();

                applicant.PreviousPrograms = participants
                    .Where(p => p.Email.EqualsIgnoreCase(applicant.Email) && p.IsPreviousParticipant)
                    .Select(p => p.ProgramName)
                    .ToList(p => p.ProgramName);

                applicant.AverageRating = participants
                      .Where(p => p.Email.EqualsIgnoreCase(applicant.Email) && p.Rating > 0)
                      .Select(p => p.Rating)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(3)
                      .Average()
                      .ToDouble();
            }

            return applicants;
        }
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work, do you have any examples of averages that were calculated that lead you to believe that this is an issue?

Comment: Well the reason it is not work "properly" is because that once I remove someone from a current program the code is working code for now. Once I re-add this user again to the program that he was removed it bring his rating down. (EX: User added to program name to test 1 and give 5/5 rating. Remove user and average rating is 5/5. Re-add to test 1 and this brings overall rating down to 3/5. It should still be 5/5 and not 3/5

Comment: Okay, might want to update the details of the question because 3 is different from 0

Comment: Oh on the DefaultIfEmpty() clause?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess is that the applicant is not being re-added correctly so the following returns an empty list:

```
applicant.AverageRating = participants
                      .Where(p => p.Email.EqualsIgnoreCase(applicant.Email) && p.Rating > 0)
                      .Select(p => p.Rating)
```

The the following just gives the default value of 3 for the average:

```
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(3)
                      .Average()
                      .ToDouble();
```